# Нейросеть для расстановки продукции

Tags: php, алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Нужен совет специалиста по следующей задаче:
Имеется набор коробок (от 1 до 1000) с основными характеристиками типа ШхГхВ, а так же дополнительными типа общего заказа, даты доставки и еще пары специфическийх свойств.
Эти коробки надо расставлять на особые грузовые платформы в виде пирамидок (типа ханойских башен (меньшую коробку можно ставить на большую или на такую же по размеру). Но алгоритм и количество ограничений на столько заморочены, что расстановка занимает несколько минут и значительно грузит сервер.
Если сильно абстрагировать, то подавая на вход несколько коробок с параметрами ШхГхВ мне нужно получить порядковый номер платформы, номер группы (башни) с коробками и порядковый номер коробки в группе (башне). Причем некоторые коробки можно вращать меняя местами ширину и высоту. Глубину трогать нельзя так как на переднем крае коробки нанесен QR-код. Все коробки стоят башенками на одной из двух сторон грузовой платформы в один "слой". Чтоб проезжающий мимо логист мог считать QR-код любой из коробок и ему не нужно было бы это перемещать руками.
Я это видел в виде 1000 нейронов (максимальное количество коробок в одной расстановке), у каждого должно быть 3 входа (по числу параметров) и как-то надо вывести данные для расстановки.
На данный момент уже есть несколько тысяч расстановок, так что есть чем обучать.
Разумеется существуют дополнительные ограничения по высоте башни и размеру платформы, расстоянию между башнями, ширине стороны платформы, но мне кажется, что для нейросети они будут не существенны так как они всегда одинаковы и не меняются.
Имеет ли вообще смысл использовать для такой задачи нейросеть и если да, то в какую сторону стоит копать?

Answer (score 1):

Почитал литературу и пришел к такому решению: для ответа на каждом этапе нужна своя нейросеть.

1. Нейросеть для того чтоб понять нужно вращать коробку или нет
2. Нейросеть чтоб узнать номер платформы для коробки
3. Нейросеть чтоб узнать номер группы (башни) на платформе
4. Нейросеть чтоб узнать номер коробки в группе (башне)

Причем выход из каждой нейросети будет дополнительным входом на каждую из последующих. Выход из нейросети 1 добавится ко входам нейросетей 2,3,4. Выход из нейросети 2 добавится ко входам 3 и 4 нейросети.
Соответственно вот так на схеме будут выглядеть нейросеть 1 [image: нейросеть]
и нейросеть 2

[image: нейросеть 2].

Нейросети 3 и 4 будут похожи на 2.
Кто-то может сказать есть ли смысл все эти нейросети соединять в одну?